# Map dictionary values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (`df`) with the following:

```
 var1
a 1 
a 1 
b 2  
b 3 
c 3 
d 5
```

And a dictionary:

```
dict_cat = {
'x' = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
'y' = 'd' }
```

And I want to create a new column called `cat` in which depending of the `var1` value, it takes the dict key value:

```
 var1 cat
a 1 x 
a 1 x
b 2 x
b 3 x
c 3 x
d 5 y
```

I have tried to `map` the dict to the variable using: `df['cat'] = df['var1'].map(dict_cat)`, but since values are inside a list, Python do not recognize the values and I only get `NaN` values. There is a way to do this using `map`, or should I create a function that iterates over rows checking if `var1` is `in` the dictionary lists?

Thanks!

Comment: You will need to unwrap your dict, so to speak, and invert the mappings. You should then be able to use df.index.map(mapping.get).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need swap keys with values to new `dict` and then use `map`:

```
print (df)
  var1  var2
0    a     1
1    a     1
2    b     2
3    b     3
4    c     3
5    d     5
dict_cat = {'x' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],'y' : 'd' }

d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in dict_cat.items() for k in oldv}
print (d)
{'a': 'x', 'b': 'x', 'c': 'x', 'd': 'y'}

df['cat'] = df['var1'].map(d)
print (df)
  var1  var2 cat
0    a     1   x
1    a     1   x
2    b     2   x
3    b     3   x
4    c     3   x
5    d     5   y
```

If first columns is index is possible use `rename` or convert `index` [`to_series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_series.html) and then use `map`:

```
print (df)
   var1
a     1
a     1
b     2
b     3
c     3
d     5

dict_cat = {'x' : ['a', 'b', 'c'],'y' : 'd' }
d = {k: oldk for oldk, oldv in dict_cat.items() for k in oldv}

df['cat'] = df.rename(d).index
```

Or:

```
df['cat'] = df.index.to_series().map(d)
print (df)
   var1 cat
a     1   x
a     1   x
b     2   x
b     3   x
c     3   x
d     5   y
```